# MinIO AssumeRoleWithCertificate API is not working

Tags: minio

I am using MinIO 20022. I am following the link https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/docs/sts/tls.md?ref=blog.min.io#assumerolewithcertificate.

As per the above link I made the following request:

curl -X POST --key private.key --cert public.crt "https://minio:9000?Action=AssumeRoleWithCertificate&Version=2011-06-15&DurationSeconds=3600"

I am getting the following error:

Code: MissingParameter
Message: No client certificate provided

In the curl request I have provided the certificate, I am not sure why the API is throwing an error that client certificate is not provided.

Comment: Could you post content of `public.crt` and Minio's server cert?